# Does laser beam (EM wave) affect magnet next to it?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, laser

Would laser beam move magnet put near it, since laser, EM wave, has oscilating electric and magnetic fields?

Answer (score 1):

For "ordinary" lasers that are not powerful enough to ionize the air, the magnet will not affect the beam, nor will the beam affect the magnet.